# Oracle 10 g -SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

How to find top 2 salaries in each department in emp table?

```
Emp Table
-----------
Row_id Salary Dept 
R1       2000    D1
R2       3000    D1
R3       4000    D1
R4       5000    D1
R5       2000    D2
R6       3000    D2
R7       4000    D2
R8       5000    D2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
    row_id,salary,dept 
from
(
select 
    row_number() over (partition by dept order by salary desc) as sno,
    row_id,salary,dept 
from emp
) t 
where sno<=2
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
select T1.Dept,T2.Salary  
from Emp_Table T1  join Emp_Table T2
on T1.Dept=T2.Dept
and T1.Salary>=T2.Salary
group by T1.Dept,T2.Salary 
having COUNT(*) <=2
```

Comment: This may be time cousuming for large table

Comment: `ROW_ID` is unique so this query won't return any rows.  If you join on `DEPT` instead, you'll get some results but it will be much less efficient than the analytic function version.

Comment: @JustinCave: thanks for your comment.. I have changed my query to join on Dept. I dint test my query earlier. Now I have verified the result. When I saw this post , there was already and answer with row_number() function. Thats why I gave a different solution. And regarding the performance ,I dont think there the a huge difference, As I am using same kind of query against pretty large tables, which just runs fine..